# If antisymmetric tensors are differential forms, what are symmetric tensors?

Tags: differential-forms, tensors

Let $\mathbf{T}$ be (for example) a rank-2 antisymmetric covariant tensor, with components $T_{ij}$. In the language of differential forms, we can represent $\mathbf{T}$ as
$$
\mathbf{T}=\sum_{i,j}\frac{1}{2}\,T_{ij}\,\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\mathrm{d}x^j,
$$
and similarly for higher ranks.

Is there an equivalent way to express a symmetric tensor? What sort objects would it be built out of?

In particular, we know that any tensor can be written as the sum of its symmetric and antisymmetric parts. If we drop the requirement that $\mathbf{T}$ be antisymmetric, then using the above notation we'd have something like
$$
\mathbf{T}=\sum_{i,j}\frac{1}{2}\,T_{[ij]}\,\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\mathrm{d}x^j + \sum_{i,j}\frac{1}{2}\,T_{(ij)}\,\left[\,\text{something other than}\; \mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\mathrm{d}x^j\,\right].
$$
What sort of object is that "something other than $\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\mathrm{d}x^j$"? What space do the $\mathrm{d}x^i$s and not-$\mathrm{d}x^i$s collectively live in?

---

*For background, I came to this question in the context of electromagnetism. The equations governing electromagnetism can be expressed extremely concisely and elegantly in the language of differential forms, but important tensors (namely the stress-energy tensor) are symmetric, and therefore seemingly can't play nice with that formulation. What's missing to resolve this (apparent) conflict?*

Comment: It would be a symmetric tensor product, defined the same way the exterior product is defined, by taking in that case the quotient of the tensor algebra by the ideal generated by commutators $v\otimes w-w \otimes v$. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra

Comment: Inner products are common examples of a symmetric $2$-tensors. Your sentence "We know that any tensor can be written as the sum ..." is very wrong. It happens to be correct for $2$-tensors, however. [You can think of it as the fact that any $n\times n$ matrix can be written uniquely as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix.]